# How to use Qt Form in non-gui classes?

Tags: qt

in Qt i add a form according below

*1. Add New*
*2. Qt Designer Form (not Qt Designer Form Class)*
*3. Then type name and Ok*

this will create a form.

**my questions are ..**

*how can i add this form to my class (having cpp and hpp but not gui file) ?*
*will it behave like Qt Designer Class form ?*
*can i share same form in multiple classes ( having hpp and cpp file only) ?*

Comment: I think it's more the other way around: you can create the form as you did, then you create a .h and a .cpp file for your class/subclass (for example) and then, go back to the editor and _promote_ the elements to what you defined. This might be useful: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt there is no really form class. The .ui file is an XML file that describes what widgets should be automatically created in generated ui_classname.h file. Just take a look at that file.

Main work is done in `setupUi()` method:

```
void setupUi(QWidget* a) {
    if (a->objectName().isEmpty())
        a->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("QBottomControl"));
    a->resize(1024, 113);
    a->setMinimumSize(QSize(1024, 113));
    a->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("QBottomControl"));
    ...
}
```

If you don't want to use the Designer, then you can manually create this initializations like it is done in setupUi() method.